# Connect cards of recyclerview to marker in google maps

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-maps-markers, margin, android-cardview

Please I need help in creating a similar interface like field trip app, I have a list of cards in a horizontal RecyclerView. I want to connect each marker on the map with its card, and when a marker is clicked the card connected to it moves upper than others with a bottom margin 20. How can I achieve this?

[image]

```
Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    marker=selected_marker;
    selected_marker_title=marker.getTitle();

    lm.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView, null, 3);


    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Little late but try this:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker){

final LatLng markerPosition = marker.getPosition();
int selected_marker = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < YOURLIST.size(); i++) {
    if (markerPosition.latitude == YOURLIST.get(i).getMap().getLatitude() && markerPosition.longitude == YOURLIST.get(i).getMap().getLongitude()) {
        selected_marker = i;
     }
}
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(markerPosition).zoom(12).build();
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
YOURADAPTER.notifyDataSetChanged();
YOURRECYCLERVIEW.smoothScrollToPosition(selected_marker);

marker.showInfoWindow();

return false;

}
});
```

Comment: Might want to add a break; after selected_marker =i